# Sqlite convert month/year columns of text datatype to date

Tags: sqlite

I have a month and year columns in my table.  I would like to create a date from them.  This does not work:

```
select date(year || '-' || month || '-' || 01)  from utilities
```

My data looks like this:

```
------------
|month|year|
|   12|2013|
|    1|2010|
------------
```

Comment: Are your years 4 or 2 digit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite accepts `YYYY-MM-DD` format, so only must care with months 1 to 9:

```
SELECT DATE(year||'-'||CASE WHEN month<10 THEN '0'||month ELSE month END||'-0
```

1');

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
  select max(date(year || '-' || SUBSTR('0' || month, -2, 2)  || '-' || '01')) as maxdate,  month, year from utilities
```

Comment: Perhaps you could suggest a more appropriate way, @LS_dev

Comment: Your `date(...)` part is correct but I can't understand why `max(...)`